# Python send mail on button click Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, email

Frustration: I have searched most of the websites and still was not able to find any answer.

Info: I don't know anything about Python.

What I want to code: I want to send a mail using Python on button click of an HTML web page. It should not open the user's email client, like 'mailto' does in html, but directly send me the mail. The web application is hosted using Google App Engine (url is like [www.example.appspot.com](http://www.example.appspot.com)). I want to also send the values in text box and radio group to be sent along to the recipients email address.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" id="rsvpForm" action="">
<div class="row half">
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <div class="12u">
        <span>Radio grp 1</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="Options">Options<br>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message or wishes" rows="3">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" class="style1" value="Send" id="sendMessage"/>
            </li>
            <li><input type="reset" class="style2" value="Reset" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference Used: I used this site to host the website

> http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-app-engine/18801/

Please help me. I don't want to use PHP

Answer (score 2):

Send an email from GAE Python is very easy, but you post only the HTML code, have you a python handler in place to do that? If not I suggest to learn and test all these tutorial provided by google: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

This is a sample to send an email form GAE python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/?hl=fr#Python_Sending_mail_in_Python

Comment: Thanks a lot Olituks. Your help is much appreciated. Sure I will look at the links provided by you.

Python handler: I am using exact same code from the reference site I have provided. Everything is same, just the html pages are configured as per my taste.